# Android ProgressBar with threads

Tags: android, android-widget, android-progressbar

I am working on ProgressBar class in android, but I can't make it progress through 5 seconds and load the application. Everything works but the progress bar not progressing. Here is the code.

```
public class StartPoint extends Activity{

ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressBarStatus = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
                while(progressBarStatus < 5000){
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                    progressBarStatus += 1000;

                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openMainList = new Intent(StartPoint.this, in.isuru.caf.MainList.class);
                startActivity(openMainList);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

And here is the layout file splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/mary_mother_of_god" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.67" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't update a UI Widget from a different thread.  You need to do something like:

```
Thread timer = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(5000);
            while(progressBarStatus < 5000){
                StartPoint.this.runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run()
                    {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                        progressBarStatus += 1000;
                    }
                });

            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            Intent openMainList = new Intent(StartPoint.this, in.isuru.caf.MainList.class);
            startActivity(openMainList);
        }
    }
};
timer.start();
```

Comment: I don't get it. Can you be more specific or post the whole code. Tell me while I sleep 5000 miliseconds can I start above method or do I need to declare separate.